# Why do we break down improper integrals such that they are improper at just one of the limits of integration?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I get that if both the limits are improper, I get the wrong answer in some cases theoretically.

For example, $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\tan (x)\,dx$$ is divergent but if I use both limits improper together, i.e. lim ε→0 integral of tan(x) from -pi/2+ε to +pi/2-ε , being an odd function the resultant is $0$, thus convergent.

But why is this wrong? Intuitively, they both should return the same value of the integral.

Comment: Your example is precisely the reason, isn't it?

Comment: You ask "why" after explaining why?

Comment: I mean to ask why are the two cases yielding different answers? Aren't they both correct impressions of the improper integral intuitively?

Comment: Is there any reason except the calculation itself which says that this integral should be divergent and not convergent?